# IBuildDetail.RequestedFor doesn't get populated after calling QueryBuilds()

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk, tfs-2012

I call IBuildServer.QueryBuilds(), and look at the returned `IBuildDetail`s:

- TFS2010: They are populated with user aliases.
- TFS2012: They are null.

How can I get the user names in TFS2012?

```
var collection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(_txtCollection.Text));
var buildServer = collection.GetService<IBuildServer>();

var spec = buildServer.CreateBuildDetailSpec(Settings.Default.ProjectName);
spec.QueryOptions = QueryOptions.Definitions;
spec.QueryOrder = BuildQueryOrder.StartTimeDescending;
spec.InformationTypes = null;

return buildServer.QueryBuilds(spec).Builds;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add batchedrequests:

```
spec.QueryOptions = QueryOptions.Definitions
                  | QueryOptions.BatchedRequests;  // Tell TFS2012 to populate RequestedFor / RequestedBy
```